# Error when trying to compile MixKit library (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, memory, compiler-errors, header-files

I am trying to compile some ancient code (last updated 2004).

I am getting a couple error messages, I have pointed to the code location and the error below.

1.

https://code.google.com/p/hmeshsimp/source/browse/trunk/hsimpkit/MixKit/MxDynBlock.h?r=71#40

```
MxDynBlock.h:38:31: error: there are no arguments to ‘resize’ that 
depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘resize’ must be 
available [-fpermissive] ... 

  if( length()<len ) resize(len);
```

2.

https://code.google.com/p/hmeshsimp/source/browse/trunk/hsimpkit/MixKit/MxDynBlock.h?r=71#67

```
MxDynBlock.h:66:68: error: there are no arguments to ‘begin’ that 
depend on a template parameter, so  a declaration of ‘begin’ must 
be available [-fpermissive] ...
```

I think the proper header needs to be included, but I am not able to locate which one. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `this->begin()`, `this->resize()`.

The smallest demo of this language feature goes like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    void bar() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct baz : foo <T>
{
    void qux() { 
      bar();         // <- bad
      this->bar();   // <- good
    }
};
```

The reason is that though `foo<T>` is a base class of `bar<T>`, the compiler cannot be sure you by `bar` you really mean `foo<T>::bar`. What if you specialize `foo` such that it doesn't have `bar`? You need to explicitly tell it "yes, I want *that* `bar`".

The feature is called "two-phase name lookup", it's an old feature of the C++ standard. [More info on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=two+phase+name+lookup).

Comment: thanks for the tip, earlier I got away with using -fpermissive as instructed, but this is much cleaner. thanks again!